# Adding Azure notification hub fails

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I'm having problems adding a new notification hub using the Azure web portal. The distribution fails and when viewing more information it says "Bad request".

I'm trying to add the notification hub by:

1. Clicking "All resources"
2. Clicking "Add"
3. Clicking "Notification Hub"
4. Entering all the information choosing an existing resource group
5. Clicking the button "Create"
6. Getting "Distribution failed" with error message "Bad request"

Anyone else having the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a transient issue creating Notification Hubs at that moment. This issue is now resolved and we are not expecting it to happen again.

Thanks,
Karl